# Unsubscribe from notifications on answers/comments to closed questions

Tags: feature-request, support, closed-questions, notifications

A few days ago, I answered a question on a meta site which was closed as not-constructive.

People are still arguing over it, leaving comments which end up in my Stack Exchange inbox.

Is it possible for me to unsubscribe from that answer/question? I have no intention of giving it any further thought irrelevant of what anyone comments on my answer.

(I won't link to it because I don't want anyone else to give it any further thought either.)

Comment: Not that I know of. In the past when there was extensive discussion below a post of mine, I've asked the people involved to just take it into chat.

Comment: I like the idea but think the effort for that feature would be too big and the use too small.

Comment: Can you request the answer be disassociated with your account?  That seems like an extreme step as well (and you would loose any rep) but that should stop the notifications

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, you can, but that's beyond extreme. It's not a completely automatic process, you might have to wait for a couple of days (if, for example, you ask for it on a weekend), and that alone means it's _not_ a good option for the situation described here.

Comment: I think the user should have an option to unsubscribe from any question he asked or answered. Maybe you want to check my related request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181096/isnt-there-a-way-to-unsubscribe-from-already-answered-questions-and-badge-noti

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, unfortunately. You can:

1. Post a comment explaining to people that you get spammed with notifications for an argument you couldn't care less about, and/or
2. Flag your answer for moderation attention, and ask for a comment clean up<sup>1</sup>

If those options fail, the nuclear option would be to flag your answer and ask for it to be locked, that will stop any further comments on it (and votes, and edits).

<sub><sup>1</sup> Coincidentally I did that about an hour ago on one of my MSO answers.</sub>