# Isn't there a way to unsubscribe from already answered questions (and badge notifications)?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to stop receiving notification from questions which I already accepted an answered questions. Talking about the website's inbox notification (not e-mail, that I already cancelled).

The same for the badges notifications, something I'm really not interested, and the number of notifications keep growing every year...

Is there a way?

Comment: These are your own questions, which people comment on even after they have been answered?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, for my own question, which people keep commenting and posting new answers after it was already answered. I agree that new answers may be useful for others, but I don't have interest in being notified about new answers. Imagine in 5 years, the number of notifications we will receive...

Comment: @JoshCaswell For all posts on a particular site, but not all notifications, only the notifications for the questions which I already accepted an answer.

Comment: In practice, this is never a problem.  I have 3791 answers and 155 questions, and I very seldom get pinged on anything that's more than two days old.

Comment: Late answers are usually either updated information, which is important and which you may want to know; a better answer, which you may want to accept; or spam or a non-answer, which you may want to flag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I posted the question becouse it's starting to be a problem for me, receiving about 1 new answer everyday for a question that I really don't care anymore. I could try to delete the question, but I think it may be useful for others, so I would prefer to just "unsubscribe" from it.

Comment: @rynah I think it should be my choice if I'm or not interested in update about old questions, it's a little invasive to force the new answers in my notifications inbox. I, personally, really don't like it.

Comment: Is this really an issue for you right now? What sort of other answers do you get? Anyways, I, personally, would be annoyed if an asker ignored my answer, even if it were a little late.

Comment: @rynah imagine you work in a different project every semester, and the questions from one month ago doesn't have any implication in your life right now. Would you like to continuing receiving notifications from old questions of all the old projects for the rest of your (stackoverflow-user-)life? I think it should be users's choice.

Comment: You can [disassociate your account from a given post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127472/166155). This will stop the pings, but you lose your rep for the post, as well as any other ownership rights that you might happen to want in the future (eg. editing). If you are "done" with the question though that might not be too bad.

Comment: This question has been up for six hours now; in that time, it has attracted one upvote and one downvote.  So far, the community's reaction is a resounding "meh."

Comment: @DoubleAA For the ownership it would not be bad. But for the reputation, it would. So, looks like there's no way? So I should convert this question in a feature request, or start the feature request in a new thread?

Comment: Tom, No way that I know of, though I am by all means not the world expert on this stuff. Your latter question is better addressed to a local MSO mod such as @RobertHarvey who has been in this thread.

Comment: I am voting to close as such since the duplicate is newer, but actually has a good answer. This question hasn't got any answers yet, so it isn't eligible as duplicate close target.

Comment: I agree with @PatrickHofman, but "not being notified of badges" could be posted as a separate feature request.