# Unsubscribe from answered and old questions without having them closed?

Tags: discussion, flags, notifications

This question is a followup to 2013's [Isn't there a way to unsubscribe from already answered questions (and badge notifications)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181096/isnt-there-a-way-to-unsubscribe-from-already-answered-questions-and-badge-noti) by Tom Brito.

#### **Summary**

I want to unsubscribe from notifications about some questions when they are either

- already answered
- old

Back in 2013 the tenor of the comments was “It is not possible, by design”, but by now it is becoming a spam-problem for me.

#### **Background**

Unless I have asked a new question within the last few days, by now the majority of inbox notifications I receive are no longer relevant to me. This can be because there was already a satisfactory answer or because I asked it so long ago, that it simply has lost relevance since. Yet I still receive notifications about new answers or comments.

Obviously I wouldn't want to flag such questions for closing, as new answers may very well still be relevant to *others*.

The old question received [Question disowned by author/moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127466/question-disowned-by-author-moderator/127472#127472) as a possible answer (as a comment). This does however seem like overkill – also I don't see how either case warrants administrator intervention.

Hence I'd appreciate an option to unsubscribe from the notifications. Since having this option unconditionally would invite poor quality questions that are quickly abandoned, prerequisites such as a minimum age of the question or having an accepted answer could be required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By starting a new question on Stack Exchange you should be deemed as lead care taker of that piece of virtual property you've knowingly and willfully created.

For example, if you build a new home on a lot, you're not going to be calling the city or cops every time some soda can or empty chip bag settles on your property. Yes, there may be times when you'll need to call them in some cases obviously, like if someone purposely dumps a truck load of garbage on your front lawn.

If it's only an issue of "I don't care if this new late answer is correct or not to try it" then just do nothing.

When it's a small issue, the way to handle is to do nothing, downvote (if appropriate), flag as Not an Answer (when applicable) and/or leave a comment.

If it's a bigger issue that requires a mod to review like Rude/Offensive or Spam then flag it as such and they will assist you.

In conclusion, I don't think this feature-request should be implemented since it's just a request to keep the window blinds shut 24/7 and let the neighbors take care of his yard if they want.