# Disable notifications from old but active questions which already solved my problem

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

I've created questions that had an acceptable answer, and I would like to unsubscribe from notifications to it. As I get new answers, and sometimes comment replies that aren't useful to me, but may be useful to other people.

I would like to keep the questions open and allow the self moderation to continue unabated.

Is this feature request within scope? Can it be?  I would also like this to be extended to old answers I've created as well. If it becomes less relevant, other community members can still edit those answers for me.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266110/unsubscribe-from-answered-and-old-questions-without-having-them-closed?rq=1

Comment: one option to get this is to request disassociation with the post(s) [as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/165773). A more radical approach that will disassociate all your posts is to delete and recreate account (though this may carry [consequences explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234518/165773) if your account was blocked prior to deletion)

Answer (score 9):

I understand what you are going for here, but there is a bit of a social contract for *all* authors contributing to a thread that, when you post something (particularly when you are asking for help), you make yourself available for any response, followup questions, and to generally help vet whatever solutions are generously provided by the participants.

Questions aren't asked just to help *you* specifically. The purpose of posting a question to this system is to ***also* help folks with that problem who come after.**

So it would be an odd state where everyone in that collaboration is generally available to keep the thread responsive to new information/replies… ***except*** for the question author who (according to this feature request) wants a button that says, *"When I get what I want, I don't want to hear about it anymore."*

That also provides a *disincentive* to keep old threads up to date.

Comment: okay, this unspoken "bit of a social contract" is an antipattern for all websites and the direction services have gone over the last decade, I'll just log out of this account and make a new one, thanks bye.

Comment: yeah, that kind of evasive activity also risks getting you blocked from the system entirely. Take care.

Comment: good luck determining if I actually do it... behind these 7 proxies